# Дом 5(,) корп. 2

Tags: пунктуация

На "Грамоте" возник спор в отношении необходимости запятой в подобных случаях. 
Уровень дискуссии меня совершенно не устроил.

***г. Старые Васюки, ул О. Бендера, дом 5(,) корп. 2, кв. 666***

Вопрос. Нужна ли запятая - и почему?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая пишется **согласно почтовым правилам:** г. Старые Васюки, ул О. Бендера, дом 5, корп. 2, кв. 666.

Возможно, постановка ее **не очень логична**. Мы последовательно указываем координаты: страна, город, улица, дом, квартира. При этом дом (конкретное строение) имеет сложную координату: дом и корпус. И на самом здании вы видим запись: номер дома и номер корпуса. **Наверное, запятая не нужна**: г. Старые Васюки, ул О. Бендера, дом 5 корп. 2, кв. 666.

**Материалы из Интернета**

1) http://www.buhonline.ru/forum/index?g=posts&t=283172

Есть почтовые правила.
С мая 2005 года в нашей стране действует новая редакция Правил оказания услуг почтовой связи, утвержденная постановлением Правительства Российской Федерации от 15.04.2005 г. № 221 (далее – Правила). Она заменила собой действовавшие Правила 2000 года.

Номер дома по российским правилам всегда пишется после названия улицы.
Кроме того, почтовый адрес может включать данные, которые уточняют номер дома: строение или корпус. Они записываются после номера дома и отделяются от него запятой.
См. Пример: Дорожная, д. 25, стр. 1; ул. Днепропетровская, д. 34, корп. 2

2) http://www.shopeasy.ru/adres-kak-napisat-korpus-doma-po-anglijski/

Если у вас в составе адреса имеется нечто вроде:ул. Ленина, д. 48, корпус 4, квартира 85, то правильно написать это по-английски можно так:
Lenina street 48, building 4, appt. 85

Comment: *Наверное, запятая не нужна:* и  *Они записываются после номера дома и отделяются от него запятой* - определитесь)))

Comment: *При этом дом (конкретное строение) имеет сложную координату: дом и корпус.* - что такое в данном случае координата?! Да еще "сложная"?

Comment: Точка в пространстве задается координатами, в почтовом пространстве - это страна, город, улица, дом, квартира.  Мы должны найти конкретного адресата по этим пяти координатам, но 4-я координата  включает номер дома и номер корпуса, хотя речь идет об одном строении. Вот эту координату я считаю сложной, ее в принципе можно бы записывать без запятой (дом и корпус - неоднородные члены в однородном ряду координат). Только никто это не делает и делать не собирается, это только теория, а в жизни применяется упрощенный и всем понятный вариант со всеми  запятыми.

Comment: Кстати, обратите внимание на английскую запись, там сложной координатой является улица-дом (она фиксирует пространство в городе).

Comment: *Точка в пространстве задается координатами, в почтовом пространстве - это страна, город, улица, дом, квартира.* - мдя? Это кто ж такое значение-то выдумал? Есть разговорное значение "местоположение", но оно только для множественного числа. Есть и основное значение *"1. Спец. Величины, определяющие положение точки на плоскости или в пространстве."* Но и тут будет странно перенесение понятие "величины" на название улицы. Мне сдаётся, что вы тут сего-то перемудрили. Оно бы и ничего, но вы этот "перемудростью" содержательно пользуетесь для выработки рекомендаций... А это уже большой минус.

Comment: Определения выше - из Кузнецова.

Comment: Пространство - это отвлеченное понятие, а не только пространство xyz, в котором мы с вами живем. Пространства бывают различные, можно, например,  посмотреть  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пространство. А координаты - это вообще  не только математика, но и общеупотребительное слово  в переносном значении (оставьте ваши координаты; вам обязательно перезвонят).  Поэтому не понимаю, почему Вас так расстроило почтовое пространство. Премудрости здесь никакой (где эта улица, где этот дом - вот и вся премудрость),  ну некоторая образностЬ может быть, присутствует.

Comment: *Пространство - это отвлеченное понятие, а не только пространство xyz, в котором мы с вами живем.* - допустим. А где я сказал, что имею в виду xyz? И что это меняет-то?

Comment: Меня "почтовое пространство" ничуть не затронуло. Меня затронуло то, что вы вводите без всяких оговорок новые, далеко не самоочевидные понятия, а потом к ним же и апеллируете, как к чему-то само собой разумеющемуся. А "правила" (любые, но правописание - наверное в первую очередь) это хорошо упорядоченная система положений.

Comment: *но и общеупотребительное слово в переносном значении (оставьте ваши координаты; вам обязательно перезвонят).* - только в ***разговорном***, я его вам приводил, это уже снижает ценность вашего подхода. И оно используется только во множественном числе. Но даже если вопреки словарям принять подобное за базовое понятие, то уж представление о какой-то "сложной" координате из него ну никак не вытекает, более того, прямо ему противоречит.

Comment: Ладно, дальше, думаю, бессмысленно.

Comment: Кажется,  наша дискуссия не приводит к взаимопониманию и вряд ли интересна остальным пользователям, поэтому я подведу итог.  (1) Я не вижу причин для того, чтобы не использовать  понятие пространства, если  оно мне кажется удобным для  описания и решения  данной задачи.  (2) Я сожалею, что мне не удалось объяснить Вам мою точку зрения (само решение или использованную терминологию).

Comment: Ну, и для чего тут английский язык? С раннего детства помню радиообращения, вроде: "Пишите нам, наш адрес[к примеру] - Москва, Сущевская, 21". Как правило, так и пишу: "Ленинград-17, ул.Строителей, 24, корпус 2, кв. 10". И прекрасно получается. Слово "дом"(в таком случае, когда дома-то нету, а просто есть некий обобщающий почтовый номер) и писать не надо. Я не пишу.

Answer (score 3):

Не очень понимаю, почему вообще такой вопрос возник. Добро бы правила требовали чего-то противоестественного или необычного. Но тут-то все под общий шаблон. А вот нарушать общую структуру написания адреса в одном месте по непонятным мотивам - это странно.

Я даже задумываться не буду, поставлю запятую эту.

UPD

Я искренне пытался разобраться в том, почему использование запятой якобы "не логично". Столкнувшись с понятием "сложной координаты" окончательно перестал понимать. Какая-то "сложная" координата противоестественна для математики, там под сложной координатой я еще готов понимать - и то на разговорном уровне - разве что совокупность простых, никаким образом не подчиненных друг другу. В английском запись адреса происходит от формы **"Baker st. 221th"**, что вполне логично именно без запятой и переводится как "221-й дом **по** Бэйкер стрит, что, кстати, было основной формой в позапрошлом веке и активно использовалось еще полвека назад ("В доме восемь дробь один по проспекту Ильича" - Мих.) и никакой запятой не требовало.  При чем тут "сложная координата" (да и "координата" вообще), не очень понятно.

При современной же записи идет совершенно очевидно последовательное уточнение понятий, корпус - это часть "дома" (участка, владения), поэтому не вижу причин приклеивать его намертво к дому. Запятая мне лично очевидна. Подозреваю (да вот и по ответу), что кто-то может понимать "корпус" как составную часть единого номера дома (как 221b) но это неверно. Гипотетические 221b и 221a, равно как и 221 просто - это три разных объекта. А дом 5 - это совокупность всех корпусов (если есть) под данным номером.

Comment: Существуют правила адресации объектов (общие или принятые для конкретной административной единицы), например: "На территории владения определяется основное здание, относительно которого осуществляется адресация самого владения. Прочим (неосновным) зданиям, строениям и сооружениям, расположенным на территории владения, присваивается номер основного здания и дополнительно номер корпуса или строения".

Comment: Поэтому дом 5 - это адрес основного здания и адрес домовладения, а  остальные здания имеют двойное обозначение, например  дом 5 корпус 1.

Comment: *Существуют правила адресации объектов (общие или принятые для конкретной административной единицы), например:* - Ну если существуют, то надо разобраться. Вы источники принципиально не указываете?

Comment: Впрочем, даже если считать этот документ общеупотребительным, что из того следует, что из этого следует? Я все равно не понимаю, на основании чего тут можно найти какие-то значимые факты для обоснования запятой или, наоборот, её ненужности? Все равно принцип последовательного уточнения локализации объекта никак не нарушен.

Comment: Мне попался частный пример, цитата оттуда http://www.alppp.ru/law/zakonodatelstvo-o-zhilische/komunalnoe-hozjajstvo/34/polozhenie-o-porjadke-prisvoenija-adresov-i-ustanovki-ukazatelej-s-nazvanijami-ulic-i-nome.pdf. Судя по тексту, домовладение - это территория со всеми постройками и адресом, к примеру, дом 5, а каждая постройка имеет свой адрес: дом 5 (главное строение), дом 5 кор.1 и т.д. - другие строения.